# Running two instances of a program at once to increase output?

Tags: speed

At work, I am running a private program which produces output which I edit afterwards. The output takes 1 hour to generate, and I have to generate 174 scenarios of this output, therefore 174 hours of processing time.

I have two laptops at my disposal, so this halves the time needed, but that is still a very significant portion of time dedicated to processing.

Would it advisable to run two instances of this program at once, thereby reducing my processing time further? If not, are there other ways I could reduce this processing time? I am limited to these two laptops unfortunately.

Comment: How do you figure running two instances on two independent machines decreases the computation time by half?

Comment: If you split the work into pieces, then yes.

Comment: The answer is "maybe", as there's not nearly enough info for us to give you a yes or no.  As a broad example: If a computer is processing the data at 100% of resource usage, then opening another instance is going to slow the first instance down by approx. 50% due to sharing the resource equally, therefore not reducing your overall processing time.  If a single instance is not maxing out a resource continually, then multiple instances can/will probably help.  Here's a silly idea: Try it with your computers and program load, and see if it goes any faster. :)

Comment: Thanks for this, and I apologise for not being more detailed. The CPUs are not maxed out, they are at about 25% and RAM usage is at about 50%.
And to clarify, the computation time does not decrease, but my time waiting for the processing halves, as I can run both computers simultaneously.